# subxt: How to submit pallet_session::set_keys() extrinsic?

Tags: extrinsic, subxt, session

I have generated the session keys using the `author.rotateKeys()` RPC call. The keys are of type `Vec<u8>` and the length is 128 bytes.

[image: Generate session keys]

I am trying to call the `set_keys()` method from `pallet_session` to a substrate node. I am using `subxt` for submitting extrinsics and I have generated a `.scale` file for interfacing. Now I am not sure how to create `SessionKeys` struct using the 128 bytes. When I hover over the SessionKeys struct I can see the following

https://docs.subsocial.network/rust-docs/latest/pallet_session/enum.Call.html#variant.set_keys

```rs
pub struct SessionKeys {
    pub grandpa: Public,
    pub babe: Public,
    pub im_online: Public,
    pub authority_discovery: Public,
} // size = 128 (0x80), align = 0x1
```

I can't see `Public` struct. How to instantiate it?

Also in runtime, i can see the following

```rs
impl_opaque_keys! {
pub struct SessionKeys {
    pub grandpa: Grandpa,
    pub babe: Babe,
    pub im_online: ImOnline,
    pub authority_discovery: AuthorityDiscovery,
}
}
```

How to convert a 128 bytes string into a SessionKeys struct?

```rs
let grandpa: substrate::runtime_types::sp_consensus_grandpa::app::Public =
    substrate::runtime_types::sp_consensus_grandpa::app::Public::from(keys[0..32].to_vec());
let babe: substrate::runtime_types::sp_consensus_babe::app::Public =
    substrate::runtime_types::sp_consensus_babe::app::Public::from(keys[32..64].to_vec());
let im_online: substrate::runtime_types::sp_im_online::app::Public =
    substrate::runtime_types::sp_im_online::app::Public::from(keys[64..96].to_vec());
let authority_discovery: substrate::runtime_types::sp_authority_discovery::app::Public =
    substrate::runtime_types::sp_authority_discovery::app::Public::from(keys[96..128].to_vec());
```

```rs
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> main/src/substrate.rs:98:75
    |
98  |         substrate::runtime_types::sp_consensus_grandpa::app::Public::from(keys[0..32].to_vec());
    |         ----------------------------------------------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Public`, found `Vec<u8>`
    |         |
    |         arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected struct `sp_consensus_grandpa::app::Public`
               found struct `Vec<u8>`
```

It is expecting a `Public` struct but I am passing a `Vec<u8>`. But how can I create a `Public` struct from a `Vec<u8>`?

Answer (score 1):

Answered here https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/issues/1261#issuecomment-1809790645.
We can see all the types here https://paritytech.github.io/subxt-explorer/